# Date and time parsing with(ex: 21/12/201115:57)

Tags: python, regex, nlp

how to parse date time format:

> case 1: 21/12/201115:57
>
> > Known:
> > %d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d
> >
> > > if i had a separator i would use .split operator. but since i do not
> > > have a separator how do i deal with this?
> > >
> > > > > Desired output:
> > > > > 21/12/2011 15:57

> case 2: 2112201115:57
>
> > Known: ddmmyyyyhh:mm(i am sure of the format i would be receiving)
> >
> > > if i had a separator i would use .split operator.
> > > but since i do not have a separator how do i deal with this?
> > >
> > > > Desired output:
> > > > 21/12/2011 15:57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work to parse your values:

```
(\d{2})(/?)(\d{2})\2(\d{4})(\d{2}:\d{2})
```

It looks for two digits (day), followed by an optional `/`, two more digits (month), then a `/` if there was one earlier (using a back-reference to the second capture group), then 4 digits (year) and finally 2 digits, a `:` and 2 digits (the time). We can substitute with

```
\1/\3/\4 \5
```

To get the desired output result:

```
21/12/2011 15:57
21/12/2011 15:57
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WgTgLP/1)

In python:

```
import re

times = ['21/12/201115:57', '2112201115:57']
for time in times:
    print(re.sub(r'(\d{2})(/?)(\d{2})\2(\d{4})(\d{2}:\d{2})', r'\1/\3/\4 \5', time))
```

Output:

```
21/12/2011 15:57
21/12/2011 15:57
```

Answer (score 0):

use datetime

```
from datetime import datetime



datetime_str = '21/12/201115:57'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%d/%m/%Y%H:%M')

print(datetime_object)
```

Output:

```
2011-12-21 15:57:00
```

for case 2:

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%d%m%Y%H:%M')
```

For better understanding check the below link:

https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime